# Change UIBarButton from play/plause programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am trying to switch a UIBarButton identifier depending on a state with this code:

```
if ([musicPlayer playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
        [playBtn setStyle:UIBarButtonSystemItemPause];
    } else {
        [playBtn setStyle:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay];
    }
```

But I get this warning (and it doesn't work)

> Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum UIBarButtonSystemItem'
>   to different enumeration type 'UIBarButtonItemStyle' (aka 'enum
>   UIBarButtonItemStyle')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the the button type like that. As the warning suggests you're actually changing the drawing style (plain / bordered ...) but with the wrong enum type.

To update the button, create a new one and throw the old one away.